# Lifetime of the object

Tags: c#

In some block creates an anonymous object and the object in the "weak link":

```
//first object System.Random
string result = new Random().Next(0,1) == 1 ?
  "equal 1":"sory, but not equal 1";

//second object System.Random 
string result = ((Random)new WeakReference(new Random()).Target).Next(0,1) == 1 ?
  "equal 1":"sory, but not equal 1";

GC.Collect();
```

Which of comments tagged objects has a greater chance to stay alive after the garbage collection?

Comment: Objects are either eligible for collection or they aren't.  There isn't a percent chance that they'll survive.  It is deterministic.

Comment: That is, in the language standard is no clear definition of the mechanism of GC.Collect ()?

Comment: There are a number of properties that are well defined, and much that is left as implementation details of the GC.  If you want to know what is well defined, just go read the specs yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well in the second example, it's hypothetically possible for the `Random` instance to be *immediately* collected after the `WeakReference` constructor completes and before the `Target` property is accessed - there's no strong reference to it at that point, after all. So the second code is broken anyway, IMO.

In both cases, the `System.Random` object is eligible for garbage collection as soon as the GC can detect that nothing will access any of its data any more - so probably just before the end of the `Next()` method call. Additionally, the `WeakReference` object is eligible for garbage collection in the second case, immediately after the use of the `Target` property.

"Greater chance to stay alive" isn't a precisely defined concept here - as noted in Servy's comments, an object is or isn't eligible for garbage collection. Within certain implementations one could reason about what's most likely to happen, but doing so would usually be a bad idea given that implementation details can and do change.